Absoluteness of ordinal exponentiation and rank on transitive models of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", page 129-130, we are given a proof that for any transitive model $\mathbf{M}$ of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$, ordinal exponentiation and rank are absolute notions. The proof basically just says that this follows from recursion (recursion on $\beta$ for $\alpha^{\beta}$ and on $x$ for $\mathrm{rank}(x)$).
I am having a hard time grasping why, and would be very happy to be enlightened.

You can see that ordinal exponentiation and rank function are defined by ordinal recursion on a $\Sigma_1$-formula, so both are $\Sigma_1$-definable. You can also check that a $\Sigma_1$-definable class function of $\Delta_0$-definable domain is $\Delta_1$. All of them are theorems of $\mathsf{ZF-P}$ (In fact, $\mathsf{KP}$), and transitive models of $\mathsf{ZF-P}$ are correct and sound about $\mathsf{ZF-P}$-provably $\Delta_1$-definable predicates.

The first thing to note is that being an ordinal is equivalent to being a transitive set of transitive sets in presence of the axiom of foundation. In particular this means that being an ordinal is $\Delta_0$ and so for any transitive model we have $Ord^M=M\cap Ord$. That is, what $M$ thinks is an ordinal is actually an ordinal.
In Chapter I.9 you have the transfinite recursion theorem. That is for any function $F:V\rightarrow V$ there exists a function $G:Ord \rightarrow V$ such that for all $\alpha\in Ord$ $G(\alpha)=F(G|_{<\alpha})$. The proof doesn't make use of the power set axiom. This means that if $M$ is a transitive model of $ZFC-P$ then the recursion theorem holds in $M$. In particular you have that $M$ will have a "notion" of what ordinal exponentiation, denote it as $(\alpha^\beta)^M$. We would like to show that $\forall \alpha,\beta\in Ord\cap M\, ((\alpha^\beta)^M=\alpha^\beta)$.
Fix an ordinal $\alpha\in M \cap Ord$. Assume that for some $\beta\in M\cap Ord$ $(\alpha^\beta)^M\neq\alpha^\beta$ then take the least such $\beta$. If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal then we have:
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha^\beta)^M=(\lim_{\gamma<\beta}\alpha^\gamma)^M=\lim_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha^\gamma)^M=\lim_{\gamma<\beta}\alpha^\gamma=\alpha^\beta
\end{equation*}
(note we are using that the union is absolute)
which contradiction $(\alpha^\beta)^M\neq\alpha^\beta$. Assume that $\beta=\gamma+1$ then we have that:
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha^\beta)^M=(\alpha^\gamma\cdot \alpha)^M=\alpha^\gamma\cdot\alpha^\beta
\end{equation*}
Here we need to use that ordinal multiplication is absolute. The proof that ordinal multiplication is absolute requires that ordinal addition is absolute which requires that the successor function for ordinals is absolute. These are all proven the same way.
For the rank function to be absolute you instead will need set recursion or $\in$ recursion. Since $ZFC-P$ does not prove the existence of $V_\alpha$ you will need to define the rank as being the unique function $r:V\rightarrow Ord$ such that: $r(x)=\sup\{r(y)+1:y\in x\}$. The proof that the rank function of $M$ and the rank function of $V$ coincide uses set or $\in$ induction.
